# Resistors in Series and in parallel

Tags: c, for-loop, addition

So for this particular program i am adding resistors in series and in parallel. Mostly right now i'm focused on getting the series addition down. What my program is suppose to do is take the user input of resistor one and then take a range of values say from 10 to 15 that increase at a certain "step" which the user also enters. After my for loop is suppose to add the value of resistor one to resistor two and print the different values as resistor two counts up to its upper range.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int res1,res2low, res2hi, step, series, i;


    printf("Enter a value for the first Resistor");
    scanf("%d", &res1);
    printf("Enter a range of values for the second Resistor From:\n");
    scanf("%d", &res2low);
    printf("To:\n");
    scanf("%d", &res2hi);
    printf("increasing in incriments of:");
    scanf("%d", &step);


    printf("The Total resistances in series are:");
    for (i=res2low; res2low <= res2hi; ++step) {
        series = res1 + res2low;
        printf("%d",series);
        ++step;
        break;
    }
```

My problem right now is getting my resistor 2 to count up from the lower value to the upper value with the increments the user gives. im assuming the problem lies in the conditions inside the FOR LOOP.

Comment: You increase `step` twice, but you never check it anywhere. Your loop condition is instead `res2low <= res2hi`, but you don't update any of the variables inside the loop, so if the condition is true once, it will be true always and you have an infinite loop. Also, `i` is never used anywhere.

Comment: what is the use of `steps` here?

Comment: for instance if res1 = 4 and res2low = 10 and res2hi= 15 while step = 1 then i want my program to do 4+10, 4+11, 4+12, 4+14, 4+14,4+15. and then in parallel i would do the same thing just dividing everything by one. @Sathish

Comment: ya i'm pretty remedial when it comes to using for loops so i'm trying to get better at them. thats the purpose of this whole program. but how would i go about updating the variables? and am i basically wasting a variable by trying to use i? @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @Zanderg what is the relation between `steps` and other `res` variables? why you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bring up `series` resister value up to `res2hi` then try this-

```
if(steps ==  1){
   for (; res2low <= res2hi; res2low++) {
       series = res1 + res2low;
       printf("%d",series);

   }
}
else 
   printf("Not valid\n");
```

Comment: so using this method would exclude my use of steps. how does this increment my res2low up to res2hi if its only limiting the value of the series to never being more than res2hi. if im understanding this correctly if my res2hi range was 15 and my res1 value was 4 than it would kill the program because 19 is bigger than 15. @Sathish

Comment: @Zanderg i have edited! now it will do `4+10, 4+11, 4+12, 4+14, 4+14,4+15`. But why you need steps here. for checking any condition or something?

Comment: ya pretty much the reason im using steps is so that i can get all solutions between the given ranges. I figured i could learn to use this example with other situations. to be completely honest i'm just coming up with random programs to write simply for the experience. i'm not even entirely sure what this would be practical for or whether it would be at all. the problem with this method is that if someone wants to work in steps of 2 than this would not work. it's only practical for steps of 1 @Sathish